# Scripting Windows Service Pack installation

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting, windows-update, service-pack

I am evaluating the LabTech managed service provider software, which among other things can install windows updates.  Most updates are installed correctly, but some, such as installing SP2 on Win 2003R2 don't seem to be working.  The error code indicates a failure to accept the EULA.  Obviously, since it is an automated update, there is no opportunity to accept the terms of the EULA.  However, the higher-up are insisting that I find a way to roll out updates automatically.  Labtech will let me run console commands and scripts, so if I could write a script that deploys the service pack, I would be able to accomplish the same objective.

Has anyone written a script, in any language, to install a windows service pack, for any version of windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`servicepack.exe /passive /forcerestart /forceappclose` should completely automate the installation.

Comment: Excellent!  I'll give that a try and mark as answer if it works

Comment: This didn't work, but "servicepack.exe /q" worked just fine.  Close enough!

Answer (score 4):

If the mandate is to implement automatic update management, why not use [WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/wsus/default.aspx)?

Comment: That would be the obvious solution yes, but I was told specifically not to use WSUS

Comment: @rotard: That is the sort of detailed information we could not have guessed and which should be included *within the original question*.

Comment: The original question was "Has anyone written a script, in any language, to install a windows service pack, for any version of windows?", which excludes the use of WSUS even if I didn't state as much explicitly

Comment: @rotard: True enough but you did also say "the higher-up are insisting that I find a way to roll out updates automatically", while simultaneously not saying that the solution had to be strictly a scripted solution or that WSUS was explicitly not an option. You can't blame a guy for trying to help. :)

Comment: Even if he'd said that he can't use WSUS someone would have suggested it. :-)